# Removing specific part of different entries from a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a script that makes an array that comes in like this:

```
[0] => 1_Result1  
[1] => 2_Result2  
[2] => 3_Result3
```

But i want it to come out like this:

```
[0] => Result1  
[1] => Result2  
[2] => Result3
```

How can this be done?

Comment: `$var = end(explode('_', $result));`

Comment: Man, user1477388 i cannot thank you enough for this simple solution!

Comment: But you can thank me:  By upvoting!  You're very welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Well it may help to know more specific rules about how to filter the array as well as how it's formed, but to answer your specific question:

PHP 5.4:

```
array_map(function ($elem) { return explode('_', $elem)[1]; }, $arr)
```

PHP 5.3:

```
array_map(function ($elem) {
    $elem = explode('_', $elem);
    return $elem[1];
}, $arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
    //Cut 2 characters off the start of the string
    $array[$key] = substr($item, 2); 
}
```

or if you want to be more fancy and cut off from the `_`:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
    //Find position of _ and cut off characters starting from that point
    $array[$key] = substr($item, strpos($item, "_")); 
}
```

This will work in any version of PHP 4 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
<?php

    $results = array( "1_result1", "2_result2", "3_result3", "4_reslut4");
    $fixed_results = array();
    foreach ($results as $result) 
        {
                $fixed_results[]= substr($result, 2);
        }

    print_r($fixed_results);
?>
```

Will return

```
Array
(
    [0] => result1
    [1] => result2
    [2] => result3
    [3] => reslut4
)
```

Warning: This will only work if you know the size of the prefix to be removed (2 in this case)